# Build C++ XTensor project as Python package so users can `pip install` without any additional dependencies

Tags: c++, cmake, python-packaging, pybind11, xtensor

I am following [XTensor-python](https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xtensor-python) [tutorial](https://xtensor-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to build a XTensor C++ project which has Python binding with CMake. The end goal is to create a self-contained Python package that users can install via `pip install` without requiring **any** additional dependencies.

The issue is that the target `mymodule` cannot link to `xtensor::optimize` but only `xtensor`.

### Minimal Reproducible Example

Here is the minimal reproducible example: ([You can follow the instruction here](https://github.com/lionlai1989/xtensor_pybind11_cmake) and reproduce the result)

##### Project Structure Explanation:

- Project structure:

```bash
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── extern
│   ├── pybind11
│   ├── xsimd
│   ├── xtensor
│   ├── xtensor-python
│   └── xtl
├── pyproject.toml
├── setup.py
└── src
    └── main.cpp
```

- `extern/` folder: `pybind11`, `xtl`, `xtensor`, `xsimd`, and `xtensor-python` are all added as git submodules. The reason is that this project is a self-contained C++/Python project. Users can use only `pip install` to install it without installing anything other things manually.
- `CMakeLists.txt`: The content is copied and pasted from [xtensor-python tutorial](https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xtensor-python/blob/master/docs/source/examples/readme_example_1/CMakeLists.txt), except `xtensor` packages are not installed and found by `find_package` but with `add_subdirectory` (I will explain the commented code FetchContent later). The reason of not using `find_package` is that I must first install packages so `find_package` will work. But I can't install packages for users on users' computer so packages are added as submodules and added by using `add_subdirectory`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

project(mymodule)

# Must be submodule. Cannot be installed with pip
add_subdirectory(extern/pybind11)

# Use FetchContent
# include(FetchContent)
# # Download and configure xtl
# FetchContent_Declare(xtl
#     GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xtl.git
#     GIT_TAG master
#     OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE
# )
# FetchContent_MakeAvailable(xtl)
# # Download and configure xsimd
# FetchContent_Declare(xsimd
#     GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xsimd.git
#     GIT_TAG master
#     OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE
# )
# FetchContent_MakeAvailable(xsimd)
# # Download and configure xtensor
# FetchContent_Declare(xtensor
#     GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xtensor.git
#     GIT_TAG master
#     OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE
# )
# FetchContent_MakeAvailable(xtensor)

# Use add_subdirectory
add_subdirectory(extern/xtl)
add_subdirectory(extern/xtensor)
add_subdirectory(extern/xsimd)
add_subdirectory(extern/xtensor-python)

find_package(Python REQUIRED COMPONENTS Interpreter Development NumPy)

pybind11_add_module(mymodule src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mymodule PUBLIC xtensor pybind11::module xtensor-python Python::NumPy)

target_compile_definitions(mymodule PRIVATE VERSION_INFO=0.1.0)
```

- `pyproject.toml`: All required packages to build the system are added here.

```
[build-system]
requires = [
    "pip<=23.0",
    "setuptools>=62,<=65",
    "wheel",
    "ninja",
    "cmake>=3.22",
    "numpy"
]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "mymodule"
version = "0.0.1"
requires-python = ">=3.8"

dependencies = [
    "numpy"
]
```

- `setup.py`: The content is from Pybind11/CMake tutorial on [github](https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example/blob/master/setup.py)

```
import os
import re
import subprocess
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from setuptools import Extension, setup
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext

# Convert distutils Windows platform specifiers to CMake -A arguments
PLAT_TO_CMAKE = {
    "win32": "Win32",
    "win-amd64": "x64",
    "win-arm32": "ARM",
    "win-arm64": "ARM64",
}


# A CMakeExtension needs a sourcedir instead of a file list.
# The name must be the _single_ output extension from the CMake build.
# If you need multiple extensions, see scikit-build.
class CMakeExtension(Extension):
    def __init__(self, name: str, sourcedir: str = "") -> None:
        super().__init__(name, sources=[])
        self.sourcedir = os.fspath(Path(sourcedir).resolve())


class CMakeBuild(build_ext):
    def build_extension(self, ext: CMakeExtension) -> None:
        # Must be in this form due to bug in .resolve() only fixed in Python 3.10+
        ext_fullpath = Path.cwd() / self.get_ext_fullpath(ext.name)  # type: ignore[no-untyped-call]
        extdir = ext_fullpath.parent.resolve()

        # Using this requires trailing slash for auto-detection & inclusion of
        # auxiliary "native" libs

        debug = int(os.environ.get("DEBUG", 0)) if self.debug is None else self.debug
        cfg = "Debug" if debug else "Release"

        # CMake lets you override the generator - we need to check this.
        # Can be set with Conda-Build, for example.
        cmake_generator = os.environ.get("CMAKE_GENERATOR", "")

        # Set Python_EXECUTABLE instead if you use PYBIND11_FINDPYTHON
        # EXAMPLE_VERSION_INFO shows you how to pass a value into the C++ code
        # from Python.
        cmake_args = [
            f"-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY={extdir}{os.sep}",
            f"-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE={sys.executable}",
            f"-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE={cfg}",  # not used on MSVC, but no harm
        ]
        build_args = []
        # Adding CMake arguments set as environment variable
        # (needed e.g. to build for ARM OSx on conda-forge)
        if "CMAKE_ARGS" in os.environ:
            cmake_args += [item for item in os.environ["CMAKE_ARGS"].split(" ") if item]

        # In this example, we pass in the version to C++. You might not need to.
        cmake_args += [f"-DEXAMPLE_VERSION_INFO={self.distribution.get_version()}"]  # type: ignore[attr-defined]

        if self.compiler.compiler_type != "msvc":
            # Using Ninja-build since it a) is available as a wheel and b)
            # multithreads automatically. MSVC would require all variables be
            # exported for Ninja to pick it up, which is a little tricky to do.
            # Users can override the generator with CMAKE_GENERATOR in CMake
            # 3.15+.
            if not cmake_generator or cmake_generator == "Ninja":
                try:
                    import ninja  # noqa: F401

                    ninja_executable_path = Path(ninja.BIN_DIR) / "ninja"
                    cmake_args += [
                        "-GNinja",
                        f"-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM:FILEPATH={ninja_executable_path}",
                    ]
                except ImportError:
                    pass

        else:

            # Single config generators are handled "normally"
            single_config = any(x in cmake_generator for x in {"NMake", "Ninja"})

            # CMake allows an arch-in-generator style for backward compatibility
            contains_arch = any(x in cmake_generator for x in {"ARM", "Win64"})

            # Specify the arch if using MSVC generator, but only if it doesn't
            # contain a backward-compatibility arch spec already in the
            # generator name.
            if not single_config and not contains_arch:
                cmake_args += ["-A", PLAT_TO_CMAKE[self.plat_name]]

            # Multi-config generators have a different way to specify configs
            if not single_config:
                cmake_args += [
                    f"-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_{cfg.upper()}={extdir}"
                ]
                build_args += ["--config", cfg]

        if sys.platform.startswith("darwin"):
            # Cross-compile support for macOS - respect ARCHFLAGS if set
            archs = re.findall(r"-arch (\S+)", os.environ.get("ARCHFLAGS", ""))
            if archs:
                cmake_args += ["-DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES={}".format(";".join(archs))]

        # Set CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL to control the parallel build level
        # across all generators.
        if "CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL" not in os.environ:
            # self.parallel is a Python 3 only way to set parallel jobs by hand
            # using -j in the build_ext call, not supported by pip or PyPA-build.
            if hasattr(self, "parallel") and self.parallel:
                # CMake 3.12+ only.
                build_args += [f"-j{self.parallel}"]

        build_temp = Path(self.build_temp) / ext.name
        if not build_temp.exists():
            build_temp.mkdir(parents=True)

        subprocess.run(
            ["cmake", ext.sourcedir] + cmake_args, cwd=build_temp, check=True
        )
        subprocess.run(
            ["cmake", "--build", "."] + build_args, cwd=build_temp, check=True
        )


setup(
    # Currently, build_ext only provides an optional "highest supported C++
    # level" feature, but in the future it may provide more features.
    ext_modules=[CMakeExtension("mymodule")],
    cmdclass={"build_ext": CMakeBuild},
    zip_safe=False,
)
```

- `src/main.cpp`: The content is from `xtensor-python` [github](https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xtensor-python/blob/master/docs/source/examples/readme_example_1/main.cpp)

```
#include <numeric>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <xtensor/xmath.hpp>
#define FORCE_IMPORT_ARRAY
#include <xtensor-python/pyarray.hpp>

double sum_of_sines(xt::pyarray<double> &m) {
  auto sines = xt::sin(m); // sines does not actually hold values.
  return std::accumulate(sines.begin(), sines.end(), 0.0);
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(mymodule, m) {
  xt::import_numpy();
  m.doc() = "Test module for xtensor python bindings";
  m.def("sum_of_sines", sum_of_sines, "Sum the sines of the input values");
}
```

##### Installation:

- Create venv, activate venv, and update pip:

```bash
python3 -m venv venv && source venv/bin/activate && python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

- Install from Github repository directly:

```
python3 -m pip install "mymodule @ git+ssh://git@github.com/lionlai1989/xtensor_pybind11_cmake.git"
```

- (Optional) Git clone repository and pip install:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/lionlai1989/xtensor_pybind11_cmake.git
python3 -m pip install .
```

##### Verify installation:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import mymodule
>>> v = np.arange(15).reshape(3, 5)
>>> mymodule.sum_of_sines(v)
1.2853996391883833
```

***Everything works perfectly so far.***

### Enable optimization and xsimd

Now I want to enable optimization. Follow the [xtensor documentation](https://readthedocs.org/projects/xtensor/downloads/pdf/latest/)

##### Add `xtensor::optimize` and `xtensor::use_xsimd`

- Uncomment Line:44 in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
target_link_libraries(mymodule PUBLIC xtensor pybind11::module xtensor-python Python::NumPy xtensor::optimize xtensor::use_xsimd)
```

- Run `pip install .` again, and the error shows `cannot find target xtensor::optimize`:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: mymodule
  Building wheel for mymodule (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for mymodule (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [86 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      -- pybind11 v2.11.0 dev1
      -- Found PythonInterp: /home/lai/xtensor_pybind11_cmake/venv/bin/python3 (found suitable version "3.8.10", minimum required is "3.6")
      -- xtl v0.7.5
      -- Building xtensor v0.24.6
      -- Found xtl v0.7.5
      -- xsimd v10.0.0
      -- xtensor-python v0.26.1
      -- Found xtensor v0.24.6
      -- Found pybind11 v
      -- Found PythonInterp: /home/lai/xtensor_pybind11_cmake/venv/bin/python3 (found version "3.8.10")
      -- Found NumPy: version "1.24.2" /tmp/pip-build-env-d762ck7q/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include
      -- Found numpy: /tmp/pip-build-env-d762ck7q/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include
      -- Found Python: /home/lai/xtensor_pybind11_cmake/venv/bin/python3 (found version "3.8.10") found components: Interpreter Development NumPy Development.Module Development.Embed
      -- Configuring done (0.4s)
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:43 (target_link_libraries):
        Target "mymodule" links to:
      
          xtensor::optimize
      
        but the target was not found.  Possible reasons include:
      
          * There is a typo in the target name.
          * A find_package call is missing for an IMPORTED target.
          * An ALIAS target is missing.
      
      
      
      -- Generating done (0.0s)
      CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/lai/xtensor_pybind11_cmake/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/home/lai/xtensor_pybind11_cmake/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/home/lai/xtensor_pybind11_cmake/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-d762ck7q/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 404, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-d762ck7q/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 389, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-d762ck7q/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 334, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 127, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-d762ck7q/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 87, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-d762ck7q/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-d762ck7q/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-d762ck7q/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 973, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-d762ck7q/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-d762ck7q/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 992, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-d762ck7q/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 343, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-d762ck7q/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 319, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-d762ck7q/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-d762ck7q/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 992, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-d762ck7q/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 132, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-d762ck7q/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 319, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-d762ck7q/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-d762ck7q/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 992, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-d762ck7q/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 84, in run
          _build_ext.run(self)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-d762ck7q/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 346, in run
          self.build_extensions()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-d762ck7q/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 466, in build_extensions
          self._build_extensions_serial()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-d762ck7q/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 492, in _build_extensions_serial
          self.build_extension(ext)
        File "<string>", line 119, in build_extension
        File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 516, in run
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '/home/lai/xtensor_pybind11_cmake', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/home/lai/xtensor_pybind11_cmake/build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/home/lai/xtensor_pybind11_cmake/venv/bin/python3', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-DEXAMPLE_VERSION_INFO=0.0.1', '-GNinja', '-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM:FILEPATH=/tmp/pip-build-env-d762ck7q/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ninja/data/bin/ninja']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mymodule
Failed to build mymodule
ERROR: Could not build wheels for mymodule, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

##### Use `find_package` in `CMakeLists.txt`:

My previous experience tells me that using `find_package` could solve this problem. Thus, I tried:

- Install `xtl`, `xtensor` and `xsimd` in the computer under`/tmp`:

```
(cd extern/xtl && cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp/xtl-install && make install)
(cd extern/xtensor && cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp/xtensor-install -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/tmp/xtl-install && make install)
(cd extern/xsimd && cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp/xsimd-install && make install)
```

- Delete `add_subdirectory` and add `find_package` in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/tmp/xtl-install")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/tmp/xtensor-install")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/tmp/xsimd-install")
find_package(xtl REQUIRED)
find_package(xtensor REQUIRED)
find_package(xsimd REQUIRED)
```

- Run `pip install .` again with `xtensor::optimize xtensor::use_xsimd`. And **everything works**. However, the problem is that `xtl`, `xtensor`, `xsimd` packages **cannot** be installed before users running `pip install` command.

##### Try FetchContent

I wan thinking if `add_subdirectory` doesn't work, maybe `FetchContent` will work. Unfortunately, it's not the case. The same error message still exists. You can uncomment the code block of `FetchContent` in `CMakeLists.txt` to test it out.

#### My questions are:

1. How can I make the target `mymodule` link to `xtensor::optimize` and  `xtensor::use_xsimd` when using `add_subdirectory` or `FetchContent`?
2. If 1.) is not possible, is there a way to automate the installation of `xtensor`, `xtl`, and `xsimd` in CMake and pip installation process so that `find_package` can be used in `CMakeLists.txt`. Subsequently, anyone can install this package with a single and simple `pip install`.

System Information:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Python 3.8.10
- All submodules are at master branch.
- All other system build requirements are fixed by `pyproject.toml`.

Comment: This has been requested upstream https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xtensor/issues/2682